# How to render a MathLive Element programatically in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render the Mathlive editor programatically in React. The code is as it follows:

```
import { MathfieldElement } from "mathlive";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const EditorComponent = () => {

    const [mathFieldElement, setMathFieldElement] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const mfe = new MathfieldElement();
        setMathFieldElement(mfe);
    },[]);

    return(
        {mathFieldElement}
    )
}
```

But the following error is thrown:

'Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

In the mathlive docs, it is said that the MathField element can be added to the DOM like this:

```
const mfe = new MathfieldElement();
document.body.appendChild(mfe);
```

But I would like to add it inside the React Component, not in the regular DOM.

I have also logged the MathfieldElement in the console, and it looks like a regular HTML object:

```
<math-field>
​
    accessKey: ""
​
    accessKeyLabel: ""
​
    assignedSlot: null
​
    attributes: NamedNodeMap []

​etc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The docs have been updated on the 20th of November. Their new example works:

```
import "./App.css";
import "//unpkg.com/mathlive";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <math-field 
        onInput={evt => setValue(evt.target.value)}
      >
        {value}
      </math-field>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

On my project, we test our code with Jest, and the import form `unpkg` broke our tests, so intead I added mathlive to our project from npm:

```
yarn add mathlive
```

And then used the code like this:

```
import "mathlive";
import { StyledMathField } from "./StyledMathField";

type Props = {
  isReadOnly: true;
  initialValue: string;
};

export const MathField = ({ initialValue, onChange }: Props) => {
  return (
    <StyledMathField>
      <math-field onInput={onChange}>{initialValue}</math-field>
    </StyledMathField>
  );
};
```

The StyledMathField, is a styled component used to modify styles like the caret(cursur) color.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work this around using the React hooks `useMemo()` and `useRef()`.

The code is as it follows:

```
import { MathfieldElement } from "mathlive";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";

const EditorComponent = () => {

    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    const mfe = useMemo(() => new MathfieldElement(), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(mfe){
            mfe.value = 'f(x)=\\frac{x}{2}';
            containerRef.current.appendChild(mfe);
        }
    },[]);

    return(
        <div ref={containerRef}></div>
    )
}

export default EditorComponent;
```

The 'useMemo()' initializes and stores the MathFieldElement in a const, then, with a div referenced by the useRef(), you can append the MathfieldElement to it.